# Vb.Net Disabled Start and Debug Button

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[image]

how to fix this problem? my program cant run the Debug and Start Button is Disabled
Please help me to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Solution Explorer. It shows that you have zero projects in your solution. You can't debug a project that doesn't exist. When you start debugging a solution, the startup project(s) is run. If there's no projects, how can there be a startup project. I don't know what you actually did to get in that state but the solution is to add the appropriate project(s) to your solution.

If the project already exists then you must have removed it from the solution somehow. In that case you can add it back by right-clicking the solution and adding an existing project, then navigating to the project file. The Solution Explorer will then show that project under your solution and, if it isn't already, you can select it as the startup project.